# Django: How to work with radio button in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating a MCQ web application in which user will select an answer and application will return the answer is correct or not on the spot.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

#Tuple
SUBJECTS = (
    ('python','Python'),
    ('sql', 'SQL'),
    ('javascript','JavaScript'),
    ('java','Java'),
)

class Question(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SUBJECTS, default=None)
    question = models.TextField()
    opt1 = models.TextField()
    opt2 = models.TextField()
    opt3 = models.TextField(null=True)
    opt4 = models.TextField(null=True)
    correct_answer = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

views.py:

```
def practice(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request,"practice.html",{'questions':questions})
```

practice.html:

```
{% for i in questions %}
    <div class="container border"><br />
    <h2>{{ i.question }} : </h2>
    <b>
    <hr></b>
    <div class="form-check p-2 ">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ i.id }}" id="{{ i.opt1 }}" value="{{ i.opt1 }}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ i.opt1 }}">
        {{ i.opt1 }}
    </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-check  p-2 ">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ i.id }}" id="{{ i.opt2 }}" value="{{ i.opt2 }}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ i.opt2 }}">
        {{ i.opt2 }}
    </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-check  p-2 ">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ i.id }}" id="{{ i.opt3 }}" value="{{ i.opt3 }}" >
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ i.opt3 }}">
        {{ i.opt3 }}
    </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-check  p-2 ">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ i.id }}" id="{{ i.opt4 }}" value="{{ i.opt4 }}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ i.opt4 }}">
        {{ i.opt4 }}
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <label hidden>{{ i.correct_answer }}</label>
    <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

[image]

Now I want to show user that he has selected correct answer or incorrect, correct answer is saved in `{{ i.correct_answer }}`.

**Can anyone help me how to achive this?**

Answer (score 1):

you should add a submit button in your html, that will post the answers to your db. Then, call the object model in views.py, instantiate it, and [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/) it the way you want.